# How to get GCP region value inside python code

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have a simple python app that I containerized and deployed that container in 5 regions using google run on GCP. I also have a load balancer.

my code now returns a simple hello world, but I would like to return the name of the region. For example, if I visit the page from us it should show me US region. If I visit from Frankfurt it should show me the Europe region.

there has to be a way to get the value but I can't find one.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_ekipa():
    return '<h1>Hello world</h2>'
    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Hmmm.... interesting. I wonder whether you can get the location from the Metadata Service? Try enumerating the response from `GET`'tting `http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance`. You will need to set a header `Metadata-Flavor: Google`.

Comment: 1) URL: `http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/region` 2) Docs: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/overview

Comment: So I wrote a proxy to test the Metadata Service from Cloud Run and @john-hanley (as always) is correct, there's a `/instance/region` and interestingly (the more customary) `/instance/zone`. Region reports correctly (for my service `us-west1`), so that's the answer. For Zone, I got `us-west1-1` (sic.) interestingly.

Answer (score 0):

The google-api-python-client package provides a way. The cloud run service's service account might need Cloud Run Viewer role.

```
import functools
import os
import google.auth
import google.auth.exceptions
import google.auth.transport.requests
import googleapiclient.discovery


@functools.lru_cache
def get_region():
    data = _get_service_data()
    try:
        region = data["metadata"]["labels"]["cloud.googleapis.com/location"]
    except KeyError:
        raise EnvironmentError(
            "Unable to get region: data['metadata']['labels']['cloud.googleapis.com/location'] not "
            "found"
        )
    return region


@functools.lru_cache
def get_project_id():
    _, project_id = google.auth.default()
    return project_id


@functools.lru_cache
def get_service_url():
    data = _get_service_data()
    try:
        url = data["status"]["url"]
    except KeyError:
        raise EnvironmentError("Unable to get service url: data['status']['url'] not found")
    return url


@functools.lru_cache
def _get_service_data():
    try:
        service = googleapiclient.discovery.build("run", "v1")
    except google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError:
        raise EnvironmentError(
            "Failed to get gcloud service info. Am I deployed to Google Cloud Run?"
        )

    k_service = os.environ["K_SERVICE"]
    project_id = get_project_id()
    parent = f"namespaces/{project_id}"

    request = service.namespaces().services().list(parent=parent)
    response = request.execute()

    for item in response["items"]:
        if item["metadata"]["name"] == k_service:
            break

    return item
```